OData Microsoft .NET - How do I emulate conditional ternary boolean operation in OData?
If I store a list of entities with the form:
public class Data
{
  public bool x;
  public string m;
}

and I want to add a computed value to the list based on the state of property x I can do something like this in LINQ:
list.Select(data => new { data.m, status=data.x==true? "ready" : "not ready" });

How can I do the same in an OData request where the service uses Microsoft libraries?
We don't have access to case function according to the roadmap. And there are few conditional options beyond that. How do I make a choice based on the state of the entity?
I have researched case and according to stack overflow questions I reviewed, there may be an If function but I have not found any mention of it in the documentation.
